# Wordpress show posts code isn't showing any posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code to show 5 posts (any post's would do)

```
<div id="featured-post-section">
    <div id="post-list">1
    <?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>2
```

As you can see, I've added a 1 and 2 numbers.... One before and one after ... I only get 1 2 ... No posts are showing at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function only tells Wordpress how many posts to output. You still have to use the WP loop to actually [perform the output](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

```
<?php

// The Query
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```